# How to hide global component (e.g navbar) on some routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So the vast majority of views on my vuejs SPA have a navbar component at the top. However, some select views such as the login should not display this.

My workaround was to import the navbar and add to each view individually if it was needed, but now I can see it causes a weird flickering when going from one view to another - presumably because the navbar component is being removed, and immediately re-added. This seems wrong.

I assume there's some way to add the navbar component in App.vue but conditionally hide it on some routes with vue-router? What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A common way is to use nested routes. Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: LoginView,
        },
        {
            path: '/admin',
            name: 'admin',
            component: AdminShell,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'home',
                    name: 'admin_home',
                    component: AdminHomeView
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
});
```

The main view will just have a router-view component, so the login view component can be displayed without the navbar.

```
<!-- App -->
<v-app>
    <v-content>
        <router-view> </router-view>
    </v-content>
</v-app>
```

The admin shell will be injected into the main view, and it will contain the navbar, side bar and what ever else it needs.

```
<!-- Admin shell -->
<v-container fill-height>
    <v-toolbar color="blue darken-3" dark app :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp" fixed>
        <v-toolbar-title style="width: 300px" class="ml-0 pl-3">
            <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
            <span class="hidden-sm-and-down">Admin</span>
        </v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <UserInfo></UserInfo>
    </v-toolbar>

    <!-- Nested route -->
    <router-view></router-view>
</v-container>
```

Then, the AdminHomeView will be injected into nested router-view of the admin shell view.

Comment: Exactly the way I do it!

Comment: I don't know where should I put the code from the answer. The answer in the stack have admin shell and v-container, but I don't know where should I put the routing or the code in the app view file

Answer (score 19):

[Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) solved this problem for me:

```
//router.js
{
 path: '/login',
 name: 'login',
 component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'login' */ '@/components/Login.vue'),
 meta: {
  hideNavbar: true,
 }
}
```

```
//App.vue
<Navbar v-if="!$route.meta.hideNavbar" />
```

Comment: Very neat approach. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 10):

I prefer a conditionally rendered component in the main view over @Edins nested routes approach.

Vue provides a great global state store via `Vuex` which makes this incredibly simple as well.

The classic example would be to only have the navbar when the user is logged in.
So you track the login status in the state store, then use a computed getter in your main view (or App.vue):

```
<template>
  <navbar v-if="isAuthenticated"/>
  <router-view/>
</template>

export default {
name: 'App',
computed: { 
  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated
  },
},
```

Comment: one problem that i've noticed with this approach is that the navbar is re-rendered every time the view changes, which causes a weird flickering effect as the navbar disappears for a split second then comes back. Is there a way to solve that at all?

Comment: This approach does not re-render the navbar on route change (verifiable by logging something in the navbars created or mounted hook) . The navbar as well as the computed property are outside of the `<router-view/>` therefore a route change cannot result in a re-render. If yours does you should share your code so we can try and help identify the issue @danmartin

Comment: In my case, I just wanted to hide the `brand` while on the home page (since it's already being displayed on a hero section), so I passed as a prop to the navbar component.

Answer (score 8):

We can conditionally render components by checking the name of the current route using v-if directive. I used this in a recent project.

My route index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: Register
  }  
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

My App.vue file

```
<template>
    <div id="app">

/* Note that this takes an array of route names, so you can simply pass in
the name of the route you don't want this component to be displayed on */

        <navbar v-if="!['login', 'register', 'help'].includes($route.name)" />
    
        <main>
            <router-view />
        </main>
    
        <appfooter v-if="!['login', 'register'].includes($route.name)"/>
    
    </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: It replicates what @TommyF said

Comment: why not use write the code in an application and see if you don't get any errors. His approach only works for the login screen if you want it to implement this for any other route you have to write different logics. Mine works for any route you want by simply passing its name into the array. Also am very sure you could see that his approach isn't checking the route name but if a user is logged in when the question says "in some routes"

Comment: Okay, that make sense, but in your description I see that you emphasise on `v-if` directive, like it's the main point. And `v-if` directive was used in previous answer. So yeah, you're right, your approach is different, but please change description of the answer to emphasise it.

Comment: Hmmm yea that's true but it's kinda difficult to explain it with using "v-if".

Comment: well, technically I can't take my vote back until you edit your post

Comment: And I actually meant "without not with".                You can say that if you were right. In this case you aren't. You simply just reacted without understanding the code. And what wrong with laying emphasis on the v-if directive isn't that what I used?. If you have a better way putting it you are free to share it as am open to any opinions you might have.    Thanks.

Comment: I've edited to your answer so you could see what I mean

Comment: Also I had to use the not "!" operator for includes to work.

Comment: ah, yeah I overlooked this. For better readability I'd put this condition to computed like this: isNavbar() { return !['login', 'register', 'help'].includes(this.$route.name) }
and then check it in template like this: v-if="isNavbar"

Comment: That's another way to put it... I would try it out. Am currently working on the project.

Answer (score 0):

in router-> index.js
write child routes and in parent - whatever global component is there write at that point,
and at children write where we want to show

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    { path: "/", redirect: "/login" },
    { path: "/registration", component: registration },

    {
      path: "/home",
      component: navbar,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/home",
          name: "home",
          component: () => import("../views/Home.vue"),
        },
        {
          path: "/notes",
          name: "notes",
          component: () => import("../views/notes/Index.vue"),
        },
        {
          path: "/notes/create",
          name: "notescreate",
          component: () => import("../views/notes/Create.vue"),
        },
        {
          path: "/notes/edit/:id",
          name: "notesedit",
          component: () => import("../views/notes/Edit.vue"),
        },
        { path: "/myposts", component: myPosts },
        { path: "/allposts", component: allPosts },
        { path: "/create", component: create },
        { path: "/edit/:id", component: edit },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: () => import("../views/Login.vue"),
    },
  ],
});
```

dont forget to write in app.vue

without router-view - it will not going to work

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I use a different way.

Just watch the route name change. I like to to use `auth.login` or `auth.register` for my routes.

```
<v-app-bar v-if="!currentRouteName.startsWith('auth')"></v-app-bar>
```

And then:

```
data() {
    return{
        currentRouteName: 'home',
    }
},
watch:{
    ['$route.name'](route) {
        this.currentRouteName = route
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. It's fine to provide new approaches to old(er) problems, but it's useful to explain _why_ your approach is preferred—or, more likely, under what _scenarios_ it might be preferred. Can you edit your answer to offer that explanation? Is this new syntax? Is it faster? Does it integrate better with different components?