# this.$route.name is undefined inside the app.vue when console it inside created()

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and I am a newcomer to this. With the use of vue-router I created the routes. But I want to get the this.$route.name inside the app.vue. Therefore tried to get the value inside the created method. But at the beginning that value is undefined.

[image: This is routes file]

[image: This is app.vue file]

Answer (score 0):

You get null because `$route.name` is not intialized yet in the created method.

You can instead use a computed variable, so this way `$route.name` will be initialized.

```js
<template>
  <div class="main-view">
    <Navigation v-if="enableNavigation" />
    <router-view />
    <Footer />
</template>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed: {
    enableNavigation() {
       const disabledNavRoutes = ['login', 'register', 'resetPassword'];
       return disabledNavRoutes.indexOf(this.$route.name) === -1;
    }
  }
}
```

In your case you want to display the Navigation component but only in some routes (the route when the user is not authenticated i assume). Here some alternatives:

## Method 1: nested routes

**router.js**

```js
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: LoginView,
        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home-shell',
            component: HomeShell,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'home',
                    name: 'home',
                    component: HomeView
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
});
```

Remove the Navigation from App.js to remove it from login / register component

**App.js**

```html
<template>
  <div class="main-view">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Put the navigation and footer component in the HomeShell

**HomeShell.js**

```html
<template>
  <Navigation />
    <--! Nested router. In our case HomeView !-->
    <router-view />
  <Footer />
</template>
```

And the `HomeView` component will be injected in the `router-view` of the `HomeShell`

## Method 2: v-if

An other way would be to have a variable `isAuthenticated` in the store and conditionally show the `Navigation` component in the `App` component

**App.js**

```js
<template>
  <Navigation v-if="isAuthenticated" />
    <router-view />
  <Footer v-if="isAuthenticated" />
</template>

...

computed: {
  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated
  }
```

The limitation here is that if later you want to disable the navigation for routes where the user can authenticated (i.e. error 404 route). This won't work anymore.

I recommend you to check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615754/vuejs-how-to-hide-global-component-e-g-navbar-on-some-routes) for more info